# show error message in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two `radio buttons` name `user_Type_mentor` and `user_Type_mentee` on `sign in` page that you can see below:

```
<%= form_for(:session, url: sessions_path,:html => {:id => "signin"}) do |f| %>
    <table width="100%">
      <tr>
        <td align="center">
          <%= f.radio_button :user_Type, "Mentor", :id => "rb_mentor" %>
          <%= f.label(:user_Type, "Mentor") %>
          &nbsp;&nbsp;
          <%= f.radio_button :user_Type, "Mentee", :id => "rb_mentee" %>
          <%= f.label(:user_Type, "Mentee") %>
        </td>
        <td align="center">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
            <table width="83%" >
              <tr>
                <td align="center">
                  <div id="loginbutton">
                    <%= f.submit "Sign in", :style => "color:White;background-color:Transparent;border-style:none;font-family:Arial;font-size:Medium;height:35px" %>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
            <% end %>
```

And below is the javascript

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$("#signin").submit(function ( event ) {

    var mentor = $('#rb_mentor').val();
    var mentee = $('#rb_mentee').val();
    var hasError = false;

    if((mentor == 0) || (mentee == 0)){
        alert("Please select atleast one box")
        hasError = true;
    }

    if(hasError){
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
</script>
```

and if user click on `Sign in` button without selection of any radio button then I want to show an error message `Please Select` on `sign in` page.
Kindly suggest me, waiting for your reply.
Thanks.

Comment: Add a simple javascript for it.

Comment: use validates_presence_of for those two fields

Answer (score 1):

Assign an id to your login form and checkboxes, let's say "login", "check1" and "check2", then in javascript

```
$("#login").submit(function ( event ) {

    var mentor = $('#check1').val();
    var mentee = $('#check2').val();
    var hasError = false;

    if((mentor == 0) && (mentee == 0)){
        alert("Please select Mentor and Mentee.")
        hasError = true;
    }

    if(hasError){
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: "login" is the form id, change your first line of the form to this `<%= form_for :session, url: sessions_path, :html => {:id => "login"} do |f| %>`

Comment: have you added "check1" and "check2" ids to radio buttons?

Comment: Why are you using names of radio buttons, use their id

Comment: do this `<%= f.radio_button :user_Type_mentee, "Mentee", :id => "check2" %>` and for other do this `<%= f.radio_button :user_Type_mentor, "Mentor", :id => "check1" %>`

Comment: yes I have added id in my radio button, but still not showing error message and also I have updated my post.

Comment: I have edit your post and replace or with and in the condition, but still not working.